# Keyboard keyup signal missing

Tags: elm, elm-signal

I need Keyboard keyup signal. But the STD library has only keydown which causes "freezes" in my program thanks to very fast changing game state (pause and play). How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the elm-signal-extra package: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/3.3.1

Specifically, there is a function `Signal.Discrete.whenChangeTo : a -> Signal a -> EventSource` (`EventSource` is a type alias of `Signal ()`)

The following program will display `True` on the screen for 500 milliseconds following every time there is a keyup on the Enter key:

```
import Text (asText)
import Keyboard
import Signal
import Signal.Discrete (whenChangeTo)
import Signal.Time (since)

enterKeyUp = whenChangeTo False (Keyboard.isDown 13)

main = Signal.map asText (since 500 enterKeyUp)
```

Edited:

I added the `since 500 enterKeyUp` just as an easy visual to see that the `enterKeyUp` signal is working. Here's another example that shows how to use it without the 500 ms part. It displays the number of times the enter key has been released:

```
import Text (asText)
import Keyboard
import Signal
import Signal.Discrete (whenChangeTo)
import Signal.Time (since)

enterKeyUp = whenChangeTo False (Keyboard.isDown 13)

count : Signal a -> Signal Int
count signal = foldp (\_ x -> x + 1) 0 signal

main = Signal.map asText (count enterKeyUp)
```

Comment: Yay, my `Signal.Discrete` module has a usecase :) This is what I had in mind when I wrote that stuff, nice to see it's actually sought-after.

Comment: But, how to do it when I don't want that 500 ms?

Comment: Just remove the `since 500`. The `enterKeyUp` signal is already a signal that will fire every time the enter key is released.